# Collapse/Close all thunderbird folders at once

Tags: thunderbird

I have a dozen of mail accounts and hundreds of folders in thunderbird.

Is there a way, shortcut or extension, to collapse all of them at once ?

[edit:] i'm running Ubuntu

Comment: Old question, but your edit indicates you're still looking for a solution.  There still doesn't appear to be a native way to do this, but there are a couple of add-ons that might either provide a solution or a workaround:  https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/flat-folder-tree/ and https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/quickfolders-tabbed-folders/.  I haven't used either one, but they look potentially helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not according to Thunderbird's keyboard shortcut list: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts

You'll need to get a little more creative, I think. Maybe an AutoHotKeys script?

Comment: AutoHotKeys seems to be specific to windows but I'm running Ubuntu. It looks quite complex to use anyway.

Comment: Hi, can you help with where to find the command to assign in the AutoHotKeys?